# Retrieving one document with MongoDB MongoClient in Java 8

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to Java and MongoDB and despite a few hours messing with this I cannot easily retrieve a simple document with the Java Mongodb-Driver client 3.2.2.

Connections are fine and I can view Collections etc.

My problem line is as follows:

```
Document profile = collection.find(new Document("_id", 10));
```

However when I compile I get the following error:

```
Java:incompatible types: com.mongodb.client.Finditerable<org.bson.Document> cannot be converted to org.bson.Document
```

Now I can get round this as a bit of googling on Stack Overflow produces the following code which works but seems unnecessarily complicated to me:

```
Document profile = collection.find(new Document("_id", 10)).projection(Projections.fields(Projections.include("firstName")))).first();
```

I am stumped at the moment I have tried changing the type to BasicDBObject but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `projection`, just

```
Document profile = collection.find(new Document("_id", 10)).first();
```

alternately...

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
// other code removed
Document profile = collection.find(eq("_id", 10)).first();
```

As you've discovered `find` returns a [`FindIterable`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html), not one or more `Document` objects directly. This is annoying at first but very powerful and useful.

To filter on multiple conditions here's what I do:

```
List<Bson> filters = new ArrayList<>();
filters.add(eq("department", dept));
filters.add(gt("salary", threshold));
// etc.
List<Document> docs = collection.find(and(filters)).into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, particularly as I will have to struggle with ArrayLists for the next part of the project.

Comment: That's why I threw that in...I knew collections were in your future :)  One other tip is take advantage of generics so you're not always dealing with `Document`, e.g. use `MongoCollection<Person> collection` instead of `MongoCollection collection`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is - try the following:

```
Document profile = collection
        .find(new Document("_id", 10))
        .first();
```

Remember that `find` returns [FindIterable](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html), therefore you need to call `first()` to get the `Document`.

I also suggest to read [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/) tutorial - you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I am sure I read that tutorial at some point but I will read it again.